# Can't save captured image to Internal storage android camera

Tags: android, camera, internal-storage

I got problem when playing with image, camera, and internal storage.
So I just about to change the code that I takes from google which has functionality to save image to sdcard. So I changed that code a little bit to this following codes...

```
public class CameraUtility {
    private String currentPhotoPath;
    private String imageCategoryName;

    private ActionBarActivity activity;

    private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

    public CameraUtility(String imageCategoryName, ActionBarActivity activity){
        this.imageCategoryName  = imageCategoryName;
        this.activity           = activity;
    }

    public String getCurrentPhotoPath(){
        return currentPhotoPath;
    }

    public String getImageCategoryName(){
        return imageCategoryName;
    }

    public File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = imageCategoryName + "_" + timeStamp + "_";

        File localStorage = activity.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
        /*
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  // prefix
                ".jpg",         // suffix
                localStorage    // directory
        );
        */
        File image = new File(localStorage, imageFileName.concat(".jpg"));
        if(!image.exists()){
            image.createNewFile();
        }
        else{
            image.delete();
            image.createNewFile();
        }

        Log.d("LOCAL_STORAGE", localStorage.getAbsolutePath());

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error occurred while creating the File",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Log.d("CAPTURED_AT", currentPhotoPath);
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplication().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Start Taking the Picture",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplication().getApplicationContext(),
                        "File was not successfully created",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplication().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Activity package manager is null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        activity.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
}
```

As you can see, on createImageFile() method, there is some block code which have commented out, that section makes my code do save the image into external storage (sdcard).
So I want to change that code so that the camera activity save the captured image to internal storage by change that code to this one :

```
File image = new File(localStorage, imageFileName.concat(".jpg"));
if(!image.exists()){
    image.createNewFile();
}
else{
    image.delete();
    image.createNewFile();
}
```

But when I try to confirm the image capture, the camera activity does not closed, just like in this picture...

[image]

That "check" icon button does not take any action when being pressed.
So what was happened in here?

Comment: where you are handling onActivityResult..

Comment: Change getFilesDir to getExternalFilesDir.

Comment: I thought I don't need onActivityResult, because, when I'm using the commented code, the camera activity was closed, but only the image that not saved. But I'll have it try

Comment: is getExternalFilesDir is working only if I had SD Card? In this case, I don't have SD Card and I don't want using SD Card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`is not getting the sdcard, but the primary memory that is shared among apps. So you can change it back to `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`.

And also don't forget to change localStorage variable in commented code

Comment: I actually need to call the gallery at onActivityResult(). Then everything run nicely.